# DB2 SQL1052N createing a database

Tags: db2, windows, db2-luw

SQL1052N is path not found when running  CREATE DATABASE....

But I get this every time I specify a path in the statement, even when the path is there and is created by the same user. The path exists and that user can create files there.  So the error message seems wrong, but presumably is some other general authentication / IO error being reported as the most likely cause.

The setup is Windows with OS authentication and a user that has administrator perms, but a corporate PC which could well have some weird other permissions issues.

Create DATABASE without specifying DBPATH or AUTOMATIC STORAGE location works fine using the default paths.

I tried c:\ C:\ and \  with and without trailing slashes with and without quotes, I have only one drive C:

Nothing appears in db2diag.log at all.

Comment: Perhaps post the actual command and its exact output? Note that it will be the Db2 service account creating files in the specified path, not the user that runs the `create database` command.